# reshape dataframe into long format python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am working with a CSV data set called newdata.csv that has the Corruption Perceptions Index ratings for 186 countries from the years 1997 to 2015. Here is a small snapshot of it:

[image: Small snapshot data]

Here, the years stretch out to the right.
I want to put the data into long format that I can work with in python. to do this, I tried to use the melt function of pandas.This code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
a = pd.melt(data, id_vars='Country', value_vars=[1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015])
```

Then I export it as a new CSV that i can look at in excel, with this code:

```
a.to_csv('Pythonoutput.csv', sep=',')
```

When I do this, I get the country column and the year column as I want them, but not any of the data. Here is my result:

[image]
How do I get my CPI values to display downward as well as the years?

Comment: Please run `print(a.head())` after reading csv or better yet post few rows of *newdata.csv* where you copy from text editor and post here. This will help us reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read your data

```
df = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

The index of your data is the `Country`, so let the dataframe know it via [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df = df.set_index('Country')
```

To stack the colums all together, use [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df = df.stack()
```

By stacking, the DataFrame automatically got a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) with 2 levels. Finally rename the index. The DataFrame could infer `Country` as name for the first level, but the second level doesn't have a label yet:

```
df.index.names = ['Country', 'Year']
```

And now you're ready to export it via [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Give the series a name with the `header`-argument

```
df.to_csv("Pythonoutput.csv", header=['CPI'])
```

Putting it all together:

```
df = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1").set_index('Country').stack()
df.index.names = ['Country', 'Year']
df.to_csv("Pythonoutput.csv", header=['CPI'])
```